# razor pages and server methods

Tags: c#, razor

I am confused on how to call or create server/controller methods in razor pages.  When I do MVC, I would create methods in the controller and would use an anchor tag to call it like this:

```
<a href="/Security/LogOut/">
```

How do I do this in razor pages?  I ended up creating a new page name "SignOut" and implemented the login inside the OnGet and used an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="/SignOut">
```

What if I have more than one action method I want to group in a file?  Do I need to create a page for every action?

Comment: @Url.Action("Action", "Controller") is probably what you are looking for but its a little difficult to understand exactly what you are asking. This SO post may be of interest to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709001/html-actionlink-vs-url-action-in-asp-net-razor

Comment: No. That is the old MVC stuff.  I am referring to Core 2.1 / Razor Pages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767851/url-action-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

You've probably long since found the answer you were looking for. For others that see this question, you can use:

```cs
<a asp-page="/SignOut">Sign Out</a>
```

In the case of Razor Pages, the `GET` and `POST` methods are handled by each code-behind file. For instance, for the Razor Page `Details.cshtml`, there is a code-behind file called `Details.cshtml.cs` that defines `OnPostAsync` and `OnGetAsync` which handle `POST` and `GET` requests respectively. For more information, see:

[Microsoft Razor Pages Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)